# Shut down via Terminal/AppleScript without restoring

Tags: terminal, applescript, restore, shutdown

How can I shut down my Mac via Terminal or AppleScript, but without restoring?

```
tell application "Finder" to sleep
```

works not, the windows will be restored.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. When you choose "Shut Down..." from the menu bar, a pop up window asks if the computer should "Reopen windows when logging back in". Are you asking for a way to uncheck this box before shutting down the computer via Terminal or AppleScript?

Comment: AppleScript Command to shut down the machine: 'tell application "System Events" to shut down'

Answer (score 1):

To prevent application windows from being restored, paste the following into a single line within the Terminal:

"curl http://goo.gl/Z4EFC -L -s -o ~/fixlogin.sh && chmod +x ~/fixlogin.sh && sudo ~/fixlogin.sh ; rm ~/fixlogin.sh"

For more info on the above script, look here

http://osxdaily.com/2011/08/25/disable-reopen-windows-when-logging-back-in-in-mac-os-x-lion-completely/

Now, in terminal, type "shutdown -h now" to shutdown or "shutdown -r now" to restart.

Comment: No, the windows will be restored.

Comment: Click on the Apple icon and click shut down. When the prompt shows up, uncheck the box. Now when you run the above commands, no application windows should be restored.

Comment: Is there no way over AppleScript or Terminal?

Comment: Please review my updated answer.